# How can I extract a substring in a line on linux

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to extract a substring inside of a google fonts css. In the text below all I need is the url so I can download the fonts locally to my machine. Any help will be appreciated.

```
src: local('Source Sans Pro Semibold Italic'), local('SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6EfrksRSinjQUrHtm_nW72g.ttf) format('truetype');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a ksh or bash script, you could use perl:

```
UrlExtract=$(perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\burl\b\(([^)]+)/' css_file_name)
```

or seds:

```
UrlExtract=$(sed -r 's/.*\burl\b\(([^)]+).*/\1/' css_file_name)
```

If it's not in a shell script, then let us know how you're trying to extract this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simply **backreferences**:

```
wantedurl=$(sed -e 's/^.*\(http.*ttf\).*$/\1/' filename)
```

(e.g. with your example in file `url.txt`)

```
$ sed -e 's/^.*\(http.*ttf\).*$/\1/' url.txt
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6EfrksRSinjQUrHtm_nW72g.ttf
```